# How could create dynamic and different objects in a dynamic component from property in XMLListModel?

Tags: xml, qt, gridview, dynamic, qml

I created dynamically a page from file Page.qml and for this no problem.
Inside this file i have a XMLListModel who take tags from this XML file.

elements.xml

```
<element>First
    <type>Video</type>
    <source>videos.mp4<source>
</element>
<element>Second
    <type>Image</type>
    <source>image.jpg</source>
</element>
```

Page.qml

```
...
Page
{
  XMLListModel
  {
    id:xmlmodel
    source:"elements.xml"
    query:"/element"
    XmlRole
    {
      name:"type"; query:"type/string()"
    }
    XmlRole
    {
      name:"source"; query:"type/source()"
    }
...}
```

I want create a function in javascript where:

1. I can pass like arguments XmlListModel type and source;
2. a switch select between type qml creation object from relative qml file (videos.qml, image.qml ) and source to add like a property
3. I'd like to put this objects if it's possible in a GridView.
   but i don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign *xmlmodel* to the model property of GridView.

Create component objects from *video.qml* and *image.qml* which will be used as delegates. An extra component (compPlaceHolder) added for handling error types.

`Component{ id: compVideo; Videos{}}`

`Component{ id: compImage; id: Image{}}`

`Component{ id: compPlaceHolder; id: Item{}}`

For the delegate of the GridView, you can use a Loader component which will dynamically load component *compVideo*, *compImage* or *compPlaceHolder* based on the 'type' property from the model.

```
Loader{
    sourceComponent: assignDel()

    function assignDel(){
        if(type == "Video"){ return compVideo; }
        else if(type == "Image"){ return compImage; }
        else{ return compPlaceHolder; }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi i followed your instructions. I tried with 3 rectangle Rett1.qml Rett2.qml Rett3.qml but in the end  Stackview push Page.qml but there isn't anything. And also, why i can't use switch in assignDel function?

Comment: You will need to perform the push from within a 'view' (eg. ListView/GridView) that has the xmlModel loaded, so that you can have access to the property `type`. Try by adding a button to the delegate of the 'view' and on its click make a similar call to assignDel inorder to push Rett1/Rett2/Rett3 to the Stackview.